# Какие части данного предложения являются расчлененными, а какие нерасчлененными (1-2, 2-3 или 3-4)?

Tags: синтаксис, синтаксический-разбор

«Графа предупреждают (1), что сегодня ночью в его дом проникнет человек (2), чтобы выкрасть документы (3), которые он считает спрятанными в конторке (4)».

Мне кажется, что 1-2 — это нерасчлененные,  2-3 — это расчлененные, а 3-4 —это нерасчлененные. При этом 1-2 — это присловный тип, 2-3 — это детерминантный тип, а 3-4 — снова присловный.

Все верно? Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё правильно.

Придаточное **изъяснительное** относится к опорному глаголу (*предупреждают, что*). Придаточное **определительное** относится к  опорному существительному (*документы, которые*). Это  **нерасчлененная** структура СПП, присловные придаточные.

Придаточное **цели** относится к предикату (грамматической основе) главного предложения. Это **расчлененная** структура СПП, присоставное придаточное (детерминантный  тип).